# jQuery .delegate(). Events not firing on second click

Tags: jquery

On a new site I'm designing, I have a top div with a link in it. When that link is clicked, the div animates to the full height of the content. This works but I want a second click on that link to animate the div back to how it was before. This isn't working.

I am using jQuery 1.5.2, hence the use of .delegate() rather than .on(). Please don't suggest upgrading my jQuery version!

**jQuery**

```
// top bar & basket functionality
        var topbarContractedHeight = $('#topbar').height(); // get current height
        $('#topbar').css('height','auto'); // temp. set height to auto...
        var topbarExpandedHeight = $('#topbar').height(); // ...and store it
        $('#topbar').css('height',topbarContractedHeight); // put the height back to how it was

        $('.topbarcontracted').delegate('#basket_trigger', 'click', function(){
            $('#topbar').animate({ height: topbarExpandedHeight }, 500).removeClass('topbarcontracted').addClass('topbarexpanded'); // ...animate the height to the expanded height stored earlier, remove the 'contracted' class and add 'expanded'...
            return false; // ...and don't process the link
        });

        $('.topbarexpanded').delegate('#basket_trigger', 'click', function(){
            $('#topbar').animate({ height: topbarContractedHeight }, 500).removeClass('topbarexpanded').addClass('topbarcontracted'); // ...animate the height to the expanded height stored earlier, remove the 'expanded' class and add 'contracted'...
            return false; // ...and don't process the link
        });
```

How can I get that 2nd .delegate() event to fire?

Please test to your heart's content at http://jsfiddle.net/4KL2z/1/

Comment: Any reason why you're doing this as two separate functions, rather than a single function with conditional execution? (i.e if bar is contracted: expand bar, remove contracted class, add expanded class; if bar is expanded: contract bar, remove expanded class, add contracted class)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple really, instead of using a second delegate, use an `if()` statement like so:

```
 $('.topbarcontracted').delegate('#basket_trigger', 'click', function(){
   if ($('#topbar').hasClass('topbarcontracted')) {
     $('#topbar').animate({ height: topbarExpandedHeight }, 500).removeClass('topbarcontracted').addClass('topbarexpanded'); // ...animate the height to the expanded height stored earlier, remove the 'contracted' class and add 'expanded'...
   } else {
     $('#topbar').animate({ height: topbarContractedHeight }, 500).removeClass('topbarexpanded').addClass('topbarcontracted'); // ...animate the height to the expanded height stored earlier, remove the 'expanded' class and add 'contracted'...
   }
   return false; // ...and don't process the link
 });
```

and the JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/4KL2z/2/

Comment: Please use `if ($('#topbar').hasClass('topbarcontracted'))` instead of `if ($('#topbar').hasClass('topbarcontracted') == true)`. Every time you use `== true` or `== false` in an `if` condition, a kitten dies.

Comment: Yeah spot on, that, thanks. Dunno why I didn't think of that as, you're right, it's quite simple really! Think it's getting a little late in the day... I'll accept as correct in.. erm.. 5 minutes, it says.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the state of the expanding div to reduce code:

```
var expanded = false,
    $topBar = $('#topbar');

$topBar.delegate('#basket_trigger', 'click', function() {
    var height;

    if (expanded) {
        height = topbarContractedHeight;
        $topBar.removeClass('topbarexpanded').addClass('topbarcontracted');
    } else {
        height = topbarExpandedHeight;
        $topBar.removeClass('topbarcontracted').addClass('topbarexpanded');
    }

    expanded = !expanded;

    $topBar.animate({
        height: height
    }, 500);

    return false;
});
```

Here's a working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4KL2z/8/).

Comment: That's an idea, thanks for your input. Always nice to see how different people go about achieving things.

Answer (score 0):

you can use toggleClass and if you already found the `#topbar` save it, there is no reason you need to look up it over and over again:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var topbar= $('#topbar');
    var topbarContractedHeight = topbar.height(); // get current height
    var topbarExpandedHeight = topbar.css('height','auto').height();

    topbar.height(topbarContractedHeight);

    topbar.delegate('#basket_trigger', 'click', function(){
        var isContracted = topbar.hasClass('topbarcontracted');
        topbar.animate({
            height: (isContracted ? topbarExpandedHeight : topbarContractedHeight)
        }, 500).toggleClass('topbarexpanded',isContracted).toggleClass('topbarcontracted',!isContracted);
        return false;
    });

});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4KL2z/6/

Comment: Yeah, it's nice, that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but here is a drastically cleaned up version of your code. You should take advantage of `toggleClass`; there is no need for *any* `if` statements here:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    // top bar & basket functionality
    var topbarContractedHeight = $('#topbar').height(); // get current height
    $('#topbar').css('height','auto'); // temp. set height to auto...
    var topbarExpandedHeight = $('#topbar').height(); // ...and store it
    $('#topbar').css('height',topbarContractedHeight); // put the height back to how it was

    $('#topbar').click(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: ($(this).hasClass('expanded') ? topbarContractedHeight : topbarExpandedHeight)
        }).toggleClass('expanded');
        return false;
    });

});
```

​

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of toggles before but got so far down the 'delegate' road that I refused to turn back until I figured out what was going on. Thanks for your input (and your edit on the other answer)